# Difference between active HDMI signal to Display Port signal conversion and passive of the same?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, displayport

I bought a Display Port to HDMI converter thinking that it can work the reverse way, i wanted to convert the HDMI signal from my video card to display port for maximum 3D output on the monitor, i didn't do my homework on this and the cable did not work except when the Display Port end was connected to the source of the signal{video card} and the HDMI to the target of the signal{monitor} Every time i tried display port connected to monitor and HDMI to source, the monitor said no signal. So i googled it and got some tech savvy blog suggesting technical terms such as passive and active, what is the difference between the two and where can i get an adapter that converts HDMI signal to Display port signal without shorting my system?

Comment: I'd recommend a solution from [MonoPrice](https://www.monoprice.com/search/index?keyword=hdmi+to+display+port+active), as they manufacture what you need and all their cables come with a no-hassle lifetime warranty.

Answer (score 1):

An "active" adapter transfers connector and protocol, while a "passive" adapter just changes the connector. Most active adapters work just one way, but they are the most reliable when used correctly. So I would search for an "active" HDMI to DisplayPort adapter and buy a DisplayPort cable because your current hdmi cable will not fit.

Comment: I need an adapter that accepts HDMI and outputs Display Port

Comment: Okay, lemme search as you have requested

Answer (score 1):

There's no passive HDMI to DP adapter, but only DP to HDMI one, which requires the source itself to be able to send TMDS signal (what both HDMI and DVI uses). Such source port is known as DP++.

If you need to connect an HDMI source to a DP sink, you *need* active conversion.